# How to request a migration

Tags: support, migration, privileges

I've posted a question on Super User, and later realized it should be migrated to [Web Apps Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

How can I do this? I've seen other users (with high reputation/privileges) migrate questions across Stack Exchange. Can I migrate my own questions without help from another user?

Searching in the Super User help section for "migrate" returns no results.

Comment: I'm gonna see if we can address migration somewhere in the Help Center. You're right, it's not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: See also: [Include an explanation of migrated questions in the Help Center](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187980/1438).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can vote to migrate your own question once you've earned 250 rep (which you have) by clicking the close button under the questions.

You can also flag for moderator attention and request a migration using the custom/other message.

Note that migrations on all questions are disabled after 60 days, even for moderators.